# deleted the ubuntu partition now can't boot the live cd of windows

Tags: 16.10

I deleted all the partitions of ubuntu to install the windows but now it is not booting from cd/dvd. What should i do now.

I was using ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: is cd boot enabbled. and possibly secure boot needs to be off.

Comment: Yes its enabled @ravery